JFR not dumping file contents
I am trying to have my process run with JFR enabled. Recently, when the process ends, contents are not dumped to the JFR file, so it’s just empty. If I run the process for maybe 3 minutes and stop it, the file gets written to. But I need it to run for a big longer. I set the max size of the file to 4G and cleared a bunch of space on the host. Is there any reason why the JFR file would only be written to sometimes, not every time?
Ive tried Increasing maxsize, increasing heap allocated to process, cleared space on disk

[edit] the question to add command line, version of the JDK and output, as text.

If you start with -XX:StartFlightRecording:filename=dump.jfr a dump file should always be written if the process exits normally.
If the process is killed/crashed, shutdown hooks in Java are not able to run, and a normal dump.jfr file can't be produced. There is however something called an emergency dump that happens if the JVM crashes. It's a best effort, so it might fail if the crash is really bad and data can't be gathered.
The filename of an emergency dump is "hs_err_pid" + pid + ".jfr", regardless of what you specify to -XX:StartFlightRecording. This may change in the future, but is at least the case for JDK 23 or earlier.
